# urllib2 performs different between windows and *nix platform?

Tags: python, urllib2

This simple script performs auto login action. It can run on my Linux box (Python 2.7) and laptop (Mac OSX Python2.5), but I encounter problems on windows xp (both Python 2.6/2.7)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\workspace\python\login_baidu.py", line 22, in <module>
    h=auto_login_hi(url,name,password)
  File "E:\workspace\python\login_baidu.py", line 12, in auto_login_hi
    opener=urllib2.build_opener(request,cj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 477, in build_opener
    opener.add_handler(h)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 311, in add_handler
    type(handler))
TypeError: expected BaseHandler instance, got <type 'instance'>
```

### My script:

```
import urllib,urllib2,httplib,cookielib
def auto_login_hi(url,name,pwd):
    url_hi="http://passport.baidu.com/?login"
    cookie=cookielib.CookieJar()
    cj=urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie)
    postdata=urllib.urlencode({'username':name,'password':pwd})
    request=urllib2.Request(url_hi,postdata)
    opener=urllib2.build_opener(request,cj)
    f=opener.open(request)
    print f
    hi_html=opener.open(url)
    return hi_html
if __name__=='__main__':
    name='myusername'
    password='mypasswd'
    url='http://hi.baidu.com/leemzoon'
    h=auto_login_hi(url,name,password)
    print h.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a Nix vs. Windows issue... your code fails on both platforms :)

this line is wrong:

```
opener=urllib2.build_opener(request,cj)
```

try this instead:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(cj)
```

you are calling build_opener() wrong. see the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.build_opener).

also, you have an extra import for httplib that you don't need

However, the *REAL* answer is:  use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) for stuff like this.  It is much easier than working with urllib2 (handles cookies automagically).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mixing urlib and urlib2

```
postdata=urllib.urlencode({'username':name,'password':pwd})
request=urllib2.Request(url_hi,postdata)
```

Comment: Falmari. if you need urlencoding, you import urllib and use urllib.urlencode(), *even* if you are using urllib2/httplib/sockets for transport.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I just glanced through it.